# SQL full-text thesaurus

Tags: sql, full-text-search, thesaurus

Is there somewhere one can get the xml for the english thesaurus from the web (for mssql that is)? I'd really hate to populate it by hand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a free one used on project guthenburg although I think it is TXT format

http://www.gutenberg.org/dirs/etext02/mthes10.zip

Comment: Thanks, what I was looking for, except in the wrong format, but shouldn't be a problem to convert (whenever I get time). Now I'm beginning to wonder whether it might be too comprehensive :)